# Upgraded react-native-fontawesome to 6.0.1, icons showing up as question marks

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

react-native-fontawesome was working just fine for me at version 5. I upgraded to 6.0.1 but downloading the new font-awesome files, adding the  new tff files into the assets/fonts folder, running react-native link react-native-fontawesome.

I closed my simulators and ran react-native run-ios and see that the icons that worked before are now question marks.  They don't show up on Android either

Comment: Did you try cleaning your build folders?

Comment: How would I do that? I thought rebuilding would take care of that

Comment: Try deleting your IOS build folder and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to install the dependency and link the library by the following ways...

Run the following command to install the dependency.

**npm install react-native-vector-icons --save**

Linking of Dependency...

After the updation of React Native 0.60, they have introduced the auto-linking feature means we do not require to link the library but they have also mentioned that some libraries need linking and react-native-vector-icons is one of those cases. So for that, we need to link the library using.

**react-native link react-native-vector-icons**

And copy the given **App.js** file that shows below.

```
/*Example of React Native Vector Icon*/
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import React
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
//import all the basic components
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
//import vector icons
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    Icon.getImageSource('user', 20, 'red').then((source) => this.setState({ userIcon: source }));
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Example of Vector Icon</Text>
        <View style={{marginTop:16, marginBottom:16, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', textAlign:'center'}}>
          <Text><Icon name="rocket" size={'{30}'} color="#900" /></Text>
          {/*Icon Component*/}
          <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />
        </View>
        <View style={{marginTop:16, marginBottom:16}}>
          {/*Icon.Button Component*/}
          <Icon.Button name="facebook" backgroundColor="#3b5998" onPress={()=>alert("Login with Facebook")}>
            Login with Facebook
          </Icon.Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

or you can follow the following link...

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-vector-icons/